# Getting the TotalResults in CosmosDb query

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do I get the total results of a query that returns more than the limit?

I think that SQL API v2 had RetrievedDocumentCount in its QueryMetrics-object
https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/azure/cosmos-db/profile-sql-api-query#linq-on-documentquery

But I can't find that in v3. You use an iterator instead, so the code is very different. There is an Diagnostics-property but it does not seem to contain what I need.

```
IOrderedQueryable query = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>();
FeedIterator<T> iterator = query.Limit(10).ToFeedIterator();
var documents = new List<T>();

while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var currentResultSet = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    var count = currentResultSet.Diagnostics.GetTotalResultsHerePlease();
    documents.AddRange(currentResultSet);
}
```

Comment: Did you try the code in V3?

Comment: Yes. CosmosClient does not have the CreateDocumentQuery from the v2 examples where they use the ExecuteNextAsync instead of the ReadNextAsync from v3

Comment: May I know why do you still want to use ExecuteNextAsync in V3? I read the document from V3,V4, the all use iterator. May be documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync() is not recommended.

Comment: @LeonYueI don't want to use ExecuteNextAsync (if I don't have to). I am trying to switch to ReadNextAsync but I can't find how to get the total results of a query with ReadNextAsync without reading all of the documents (and that would be extremely slow in our case).

Answer (score 0):

I assume `query` is your `IQueryable<>`? (Please don't use `var` in pasted code, it really helps to be able to read the types.) In that case you can get the count by

```
int totalCount = await query.CountAsync();
```

See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.linq.cosmoslinqextensions.countasync?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: Yes (or IOrderedQueryable  but that does not matter probably). Good point, I updated my example.

Comment: But I don't want to make one query for the result and anotherone for the count. I want to make one query for both and if the number of total results is more than my specified Take, I want the total count and not just the same number as the Take.

Comment: I see. The total count is not automatically computed in SDK v3, AFAIK, in which case you will need two calls. :(

Comment: I guess we have too. It is just strange and disappointing that they would drop such a good feature in the new versions.